# Access Virtualbox VM in CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I need to run Virtualbox virtual machines from CLI (headless mode). I would like to know if I can have a shell in the VM? I tried searching for help but everybody just writes about the start / stop VMs and adding / removing peripherals, etc. which I am not interested. I would like to get the IP address of the VM, is it possible? 
Is it programmatically possible to write a script which will start the VM, execute few steps and shutdown the VM?

I tried few commands from help using controlvm, modifyvm like vrdp/vrde but no success so far.

Any suggestions/links would be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Managing the VM from the host is possible. But doing something in the guest system is entirely separate and highly depend on what OS is running on guest system.

Comment: @Jay do you mean to say only in selected OS we can do something in the guest VMs? If so then where / how do I find out which OS supports it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend you look at vagrant. http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/index.html

Typically vagrant starts your vm with port 22 (the ssh port) forwarded to 2222.

So even without vagrant you could try ssh'ing to 127.0.0.1:2222